# Question about functions satisfying $h(f(x)) = f(g(x))$, where $g$ and $h$ are bijective functions from $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

If $\forall g$, such that g is bijective and $f(g(x)) \neq g(f(x))$, there exists an h, $h(f(x)) = f(g(x))$, and $h$ is bijective, what can be said about $f$?

We also know that there exist some $x$, such that composition of $f$ and $g$ does not commute. $f$ is not the constant function, i.e., $\exists x_1, x_2, f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

I am most interested in trying to see if $f$ is bijective or injective.

I have derived the following:

1. the domain of $f$ = $dom(G)$. Therefore, if $f$ is surjective, it must also be bijective.
2. Using $\exists x_1, x_2, f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$, I can show $f(g(g(x_1)) \neq f(g(g(x_2))$. I was trying to use this line of reasoning to show that $f$ must be surjective, but obviously, if $g(g(g(x_1) = x_1$, this is line of reasoning will not work.

Comment: From just the information in the title, you can't really expect to be able to say much about $f$, for if $g = h$ are both the identity, the condition on $f$ becomes vacuous

Comment: The statement h(f(x) = f(g(x)) holds for all g

Comment: That confused me; for you say for all g but then you impose a condition on $g$; it being bijective. Can you clarify? It would also help if all the information is given is not spread out between the title and the body of the question; please put it all in one place

Comment: Yeah sorry, the title cannot be longer than a certain length. But the question is: If $\forall g$, s.t g is bijective and $f(g(x)) \neq g(f(x))$, and $f$ is not the constant function, there exists $h(f(x)) = f(g(x))$, and $h$ is also bijective what can be said about $f$?

Comment: @text_math you never said anything about "there exists $h$" in title or body, and that really is important.  You don't need to cram it all into the title, (in fact the body of your post without the title should speak for itself), just make the body of your post clearly state all assumptions and quantifiers.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have edited the question now. Thanks!

Comment: Titles should not be the statement problem. Posts don't start at the subject line (a letter doesn't begin on the envelope). Title should give an indication aboutbthe subject matter of the query, and all of the relevant information should be in the body of the post.

Comment: Updated the title and body

Comment: It's also not clear what $f(g(x))\neq g(f(x))$ means.  Does that mean for all $x$, they are unequal, or for some $x$, they are unequal?

Comment: for some -- the idea being you can assume the composition of $f$ and does not commute in general for all $x$!

Comment: @text_math in your post you write "for all"

Comment: Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Also let me say it would really help if you clarified what the domain and target for these functions are.  Are they all maps from a particular set $S$ to itself?  You can't talk about being surjective without defining what the target of a function is.

Comment: Umm I think the question should be agnostic to the domain and range, but we can assume they are functions over the integers

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy the condition, it is both necessary and sufficient that $f$ is injective.  ($f$ need NOT be surjective).  In fact this is true with or without requiring that $g$ not commute with $f$.  Also as you mentioned in comments we may replace $\mathbb Z$ with an arbitrary set and this result will still be true.

#### Necessity

$f$ must be injective, since otherwise let $x_1,x_2$ be such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, and since $f$ is nonconstant, let $x_3$ satisfy $f(x_3)\neq f(x_1)$.  Define
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
x_1 & x=x_3\\
x_3 & x=x_1\\
x & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$
Then no matter how we define $h$, we will have $h(f(x_1))=h(f(x_2))$, but $$f(g(x_1))=f(x_3)\neq f(x_2) =f(g(x_2))\text{,}$$
contradicting the condition on $h$.
(Notice also that $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$, so either $g(f(x_1))\neq f(g(x_1))$ or $g(f(x_2))\neq f(g(x_2))$, so $g$ satisfies the noncommuting requirement.)

#### Sufficiency

If $f$ is injective, then $f^{-1}$ is defined on $f(\mathbb Z)$, so we may define
$$
h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(g(f^{-1}(x))) & x\in f(\mathbb Z)\text{,}\\
x & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that $h$ is a bijection with inverse
$$
h^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}
f(g^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))) & x\in f(\mathbb Z)\text{,}\\
x & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
and $h$ satisfies the desired criterion, since $$h(f(x))=f(g(f^{-1}(f(x))))=f(g(x))\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew the sufficiency direction, but was completely stumped by the necessity.